# Using linQ to perform a simple select where

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, sql-server-2012

I am using VS2013 with SQL server 2012, VB.net.  I am developing a web application.

Let me say before I ask the question that this will probably be extremely simple for this board but I have not been able to find this through googling.

I have an SQL table that holds some data, two columns (settingName (nvarchar) and settingValue (float)).  I want to do the following but using LinQ.

```
SELECT Settingvalue
FROM Settings
WHERE settingName = 'Name1'
```

I have the following so far in VB.

```
    Dim db As New GMConnectionDataContext

    Dim result = From a In db.Settings
                 Where a.SettingName = "Name1"
                 Select a.SettingValue


    txtEgdon.Text = result
```

This doesn't work as result is a double but if I add .tostring to result then the output in the text box is the full linq query not the result I am looing for.

I just need to understand this simple query so I can build on it but I just cant get it and any help offered would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your result is an `IQueryable` and not a single value(even if you expect it to be). This is also why `ToString` will get you the SQL that will be run against your DB.

You need to get either the `First` or if you are really sure this would be a single value get `Single`. The `OrDefault`s are used in the case that no value is returned so the result will be null.

A Few options:

```
// You expect 1 to many results and get the first
txtEgdon.Text = result.First().ToString()
// You expect 0 to many results and get the first or null in case of zero results 
txtEgdon.Text = result.FirstOrDefault().ToString() 
// You expect exactly 1 result and get it (you will get an exception if no results are returned)
txtEgdon.Text = result.Single().ToString() 
// You expect exactly 0 or 1 results and get null or the result
txtEgdon.Text = result.SingleOrDefault().ToString()
```

I would prefer the `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: With `Option Strict On` you would need to use `ToString` when populating the text box.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway there is no suggestion about having Option Strict On, is there?

Comment: It _should_ be on and I just wanted to point out that if it _is_ on, your code would not compile.  In my opinion, code samples for VB.Net should be written as if `Option Strict` was on to encourage best practices.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway i have to admit i cannot argue with your reasoning. I will update my answer.